# Image fade in/out with pure JS causes images to stick

Tags: javascript, html

I have three images that I want to fade in and out on `mouseover/mouseout` events (Can't figure out whether I should use `mouseover/mouseenter` but that seems tertiary) After doing some research I found a solution that works pretty well with some minor adjustments but I've come to one last problem, if I move quickly from one image to the next the first image sticks rather than fades out.

I've tried a number of things including giving each image separate timers, modifying how the images fade and much more.

I recreated it in a JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dm9cgysL/

Here is the JS fiddle code:

HTML:

```html
<img id="project1-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEDaxij.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; opacity: 0;">
<img id="project2-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEDaxij.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; opacity: 0;">
<img id="project3-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEDaxij.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; opacity: 0;">
```

Javascript:

```
var timer;

function handleHover(imageId, out) {
  let image = document.getElementById(imageId);

  if (image) {
    handleFade(image, out);
  }
}

function handleFade(element, out) {
  clearInterval(timer);
  //let op = parseInt(element.style.opacity); // initial opacity
  let op = out ? 1 : 0;
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (out) {
      if (op <= 0) {
        element.style.opacity = 0.1;
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      element.style.opacity = op;
      op -= 0.1;
    } else {
      if (op >= 1) {
        element.style.opacity = 0.9;
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      element.style.opacity = op;
      op += 0.1;
    }
  }, 10);
}

let e = document.getElementById('project3-img');
e.onmouseenter = () => handleHover("project3-img", false)
e.onmouseleave = () => handleHover("project3-img", true)

let f = document.getElementById('project2-img');
f.onmouseenter = () => handleHover("project2-img", false)
f.onmouseleave = () => handleHover("project2-img", true)

let g = document.getElementById('project1-img');
g.onmouseenter = () => handleHover("project1-img", false)
g.onmouseleave = () => handleHover("project1-img", true)
```

I expect the images to fade in on hover and fade out when the mouse leaves the element. It works if you focus only on a single element but going from one element to another element causes the first element to stick, I'm trying to get the fade to finish on the first element and the fade to start on the second element without any of the animations sticking.

Thanks in advance, I realize the code is a bit messy and appreciate you bearing with me on that.

Comment: it looks like the problem is you cleared timer before the animation finishes if you move from one element to another.

Comment: How can there only be a single `timer` value when it's possible multiple elements are being timed at the same time?

Comment: @ChrisLi if I dont clear the timer there, the animations run worse.

Comment: @GershomMaes I tried using seperate timers and it made no difference. If you want to fiddle with it and show me how to handle it, that would be awesome, I just couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code lets us make an element that fades in and out, independent of any other fade-y elements that may exist on the page.

A `tryDoFade` function checks to see if the opacity of the element should be undergoing change. If the opacity is undergoing change it makes the changes (using `requestAnimationFrame`, which should be smoother than `setInterval`), and continues to check if changes should be made. Once fully opaque or transparent, `tryDoFade` will stop calling itself.

```js
let makeFadeyElem = () => {
  let elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.style.display = 'inline-block';
  elem.style.width = '100px';
  elem.style.height = '100px';
  elem.style.backgroundColor = '#ff8000';
  elem.style.opacity = 0;
  
  let opacity = 0;    // Current raw opacity value
  let fadeInc = 0.05; // Amount to fade each frame
  let state = 'disappeared'; // disappeared, appearing, appeared, disappearing
  
  let tryDoFade = () => requestAnimationFrame(() => {

    let changed = false;
    if (state === 'appearing' && opacity < 1) opacity = Math.min(1, opacity + fadeInc);
    else if (state === 'disappearing' && opacity > 0) opacity = Math.max(0, opacity - fadeInc);

    elem.style.opacity = opacity;

    // Enter a rest state if opacity maxes out in either direction
    if (opacity === 0) state = 'disappeared';
    else if (opacity === 1) state = 'appeared';

    // Keep animating if not in a rest state
    if (state === 'disappearing' || state === 'appearing') tryDoFade();

  });
  
  // Mousing over or out set the element into a non-rest state
  elem.onmouseover = () => (state = 'appearing') && tryDoFade();
  elem.onmouseout = () => (state = 'disappearing') && tryDoFade();
  
  return elem;
};

// Make 30 such elements:
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) document.body.appendChild(makeFadeyElem());
```

Comment: Does this only work if you create the element using the outer function? The elements I'm using to trigger the animations already exist on my DOM

Comment: This can easily work using a pre-existing element - just make `elem` a parameter, instead of the result of `document.createElement('div')`, and pass in the correct element to use.

Comment: This produced the same results as the code I posted above. Here is the fiddle where I recreated what I did in my project using this method: https://jsfiddle.net/dm9cgysL/1/

Comment: I don't see a `makeFadeyElem` function in your example. The reason my code can support 30 divs that independently fade is because 30 calls to `makeFadeyElem` occur. You've copy/pasted the body of the `makeFadeyElem` function, which is essentially equivalent to calling the function once.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, sorry I was just misunderstanding. Let me see how I can integrate this into my project this way.

Comment: Okay heres the catch, and I guess I should have made this clear from the beginning but I didn't see how it would matter. The element I'm hovering on is not the same element that I am trying to fade in or out. It's a different element overlayed over the image I'm fading.

Comment: You may want to mark this answer and create a new question! If you explain your full situation I'll give you another answer :)

Comment: I posted a new question more accurately describing the situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665728/triggering-a-fade-in-fade-out-from-another-element-causes-the-fading-element-to