# Triggering a fade in/fade out from another element causes the fading element to stick when switching trigger elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I asked a question earlier about fading an element in and out which was answered with the solution I will post later on, however I left out some information that proves to be more relevant than I originally realized.

I am trying to fade an element in on the hover of a separate trigger element and out when the mouse leaves that same trigger element. currently if I move from one trigger element to another trigger element the first element doesn't fade out.

I have tried a number of solutions including the following two jsfiddles which handle the fading fine but still have the issue I was having occuring when switching trigger elements.

Here is the current mock up of code I'm using:

```html
<img id="project1-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEDaxij.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; opacity: 0;">
<img id="project2-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEDaxij.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; opacity: 0;">
<img id="project3-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEDaxij.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; opacity: 0;">

<span id="trigger1">
111111111111
</span>

<span id="trigger2">
22222222222
</span >

<span id="trigger3">
33333333333
</span>
```

```
let state = "disappeared"; // disappeared, appearing, appeared, disappearing
let opacity = 0; // Current raw opacity value
let fadeInc = 0.05; // Amount to fade each frame

let findElementToFade = (imageId) => {
    let elem = document.getElementById(imageId);
        tryDoFade(elem);
}

let tryDoFade = elem =>
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    //console.log("called with " + imageId);
    //let state = "disappeared"; // disappeared, appearing, appeared, disappearing

    let changed = false;
    if (state === "appearing" && opacity < 1)
      opacity = Math.min(1, opacity + fadeInc);
    else if (state === "disappearing" && opacity > 0)
      opacity = Math.max(0, opacity - fadeInc);

    elem.style.opacity = opacity;

    // Enter a rest state if opacity maxes out in either direction
    if (opacity === 0) state = "disappeared";
    else if (opacity === 1) state = "appeared";

    // Keep animating if not in a rest state
    if (state === "disappearing" || state === "appearing") tryDoFade(elem);
  });

let e = document.getElementById('trigger1');
e.onmouseover=() =>(state = "appearing") && findElementToFade(`project3-img`)
e.onmouseout=() =>(state = "disappearing") && findElementToFade(`project3-img`)

let f = document.getElementById('trigger2');
f.onmouseover=() =>(state = "appearing") && findElementToFade(`project2-img`)
f.onmouseout=() =>(state = "disappearing") && findElementToFade(`project2-img`)

let g = document.getElementById('trigger3');
g.onmouseover=() =>(state = "appearing") && findElementToFade(`project1-img`)
g.onmouseout=() =>(state = "disappearing") && findElementToFade(`project1-img`)
```

Here are the JsFiddles I've been playing with:
https://jsfiddle.net/dm9cgysL/1/

This is the solution to my last question which doesn't work in my particular case:
https://jsfiddle.net/03sgm1ot/

Here is a jsfiddle that is more accurate to what I am trying to do: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dm9cgysL/6/

I expect for each of the elements to fade in and out independently as soon as the mouse enters/exits the trigger elements, currently if I go from one trigger element to the next it causes the previous fade to stop in its tracks leaving the element on the page.

RESOLVED: I modified the answer I marked as the answer to fit my needs here is what I did:

CSS:

```css
img.transition {
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
  opacity: 0;
}

img.transition.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The images I used have a class name of `transition`:

```html
<img id="project1-img" src="/static/media/mtg.4c420286.png" class="ui fluid image transition" >
```

My trigger elements have the following mouse events:

```
onMouseOver={() => handleTransition(`project1-img`)}
onMouseOut={() => handleTransition(`project1-img`)}
```

And my handleTransition function is as follows:

```
const handleTransition = id => {
  let target = document.getElementById(id);
  if (target.classList.contains("visible")) {
    target.classList.remove("visible");
  } else {
    target.classList.add("visible");
  }
};
```

This is a much cleaner solution to the issue I was having, I didn't realize that css had built in transitions like this and I'm going to have to look into them further. Thanks to everyone who took a look and thanks to GammaGames for the solution that got me here.

Comment: Just curious, why use javascript instead of css with transitions? It's a lot easier: https://jsfiddle.net/o9vdm207/ and has nearly the same support as the opacity property https://caniuse.com/#search=transition

Comment: Candidly, I'm using react for my project and react-semantic-ui and I'm not very comfortable with css. What you've got doesnt solve my issue as I'm trying to trigger hover of one element from a seperate element.

Comment: Ah, sorry I'm not familiar with react but I have used SUI quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning css would really help with this case, especially since you're modifying the element's css manually with the `style` attribute anyway. I'm sure you could use `data` attributes to store timeout ids or something hacky, but for a simple solution I:

1. Add a `data-target` attribute to each `<span>` that I want to listen to
2. On mouseover, add a `visible` class to the image with the matching target id
3. On mouseout, remove the `visible` class to the image with the matching target id

`img` tags with the `transition` class have 0 opacity by default and transition with 0.25s time. The `visible` class makes the opacity into 1, and the element automatically transitions. You can read more about transitions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

```js
$(".trigger").on("mouseover", function() {
  let target = $(this).data("target");
  $(`#${target}`).addClass("visible");
});

$(".trigger").on("mouseout", function() {
  let target = $(this).data("target");
  $(`#${target}`).removeClass("visible");
});
```

```css
img.transition {
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
  opacity: 0;
}

img.transition.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img class="transition" id="project1-img" src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img class="transition" id="project2-img" src="https://picsum.photos/100">
  <img class="transition" id="project3-img" src="https://picsum.photos/100">
</div>

<div>
  <span class="trigger" data-target="project3-img">
    111111111111
  </span>
  <span class="trigger" data-target="project2-img">
    22222222222
  </span >
  <span class="trigger" data-target="project1-img">
    33333333333
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Brother, thanks so much, this wasn't exactly what I used, but it got me where I needed to be, I'll post my full solution in the question for anyone looking to do the same thing. Thanks again, I appreciate the push in this direction

Comment: @AustinMelchior Glad I could help! Good job modifying my answer to get what you wanted, it looks great!